# How can I scrape an embedded Google Calendar from a URL?

Tags: html, ios, url, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm creating an iOS app and I am trying to display a Google Calendar from a webpage. The Calendar is public. Right now I am displaying the whole page in a UIWebView which is full of buttons that takes users to outside links. I only want to display the calendar. How can I scrape just the calendar from the url and display it in the webview?

I've tried:

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/username%40gmail.com/public/basic

But it returns a white screen saying `Forbidden Error 403`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. This is the code that I used. You can tweak the data to get exactly what you want but this worked for me. In the gcal string just change USER@gmail.com to your calendar's gmail account. I had to play around with the size to get it to fill the screen just right as well.

```
    NSString *gcal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=%f\"/><iframe src=\"http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=1&amp;showTabs=1&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;src=USER@gmail.com&amp;color=%%23BE6D00&amp;ctz=America%%2FNew_York\" scrolling=\"no\" style=\"border-width: 0pt;\" mce_style=\" border-width:0 \" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"%f\" width=\"%f\"></iframe>",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-70,self.view.frame.size.width-8];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:gcal baseURL:nil];
```